# What is this object name and how it works?

Tags: cockpit, feature-identification

[image: Cessna 150/152's cockpit view]

Photo is from [here](http://digitalpilotschool.com/5-light-aircraft-cockpit-images/).

I believe that it something like steer on a car. But seems that it has function or control more than just turning left or right. Is any different between left and right?

Comment: Does it honk when you press it?

Comment: @Jimmy Indeed, some aircraft have horns!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a yoke.  Turning it left or right rolls the airplane.  Pulling it towards you pitches up.  Pushing it away from you pitches down.

Comment: How about turning the nose wheel when it preparing for take off and when it going to park (what is the suitable name for this)? Or, is turning the nose wheel during preparation for take off also using aileron?

Comment: The nose wheel is usually steered with the rudder pedals.  Sometimes (especially with tail wheel airplanes) the "steering" tire just casters, so when taxiing you steer by braking the left and right main wheels separately.  Some larger aircraft use a separate "tiller" for steering when taxiing.

Comment: Unless you are flying an Ercoupe, I think that's the only aircraft where turning the yoke (wheel in an Ercoupe) turns the nose wheel.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune, will be still effective to control the nose wheel with the very low speed like during preparation for take of or "park" which the speed sometimes something near 0 km/h? I doubt really works due the power hitting the rudder is not sufficient.

Comment: @RonBeyer, are you saying that only Ercoupe that nose wheel is controlled with rudder?

Comment: Ercoupe steered the nosewheel with yoke because it had no rudder pedals.  @aircraftlover study this carefully: https://www.si.edu/object/nasm_A19790677000.

Comment: @aircraftlover Nose wheel is controlled with rudder PEDALS, not with rudder.  Spend a few weeks with textbooks from your library or with someone friendly at your local airport.  That will teach you the basics  more gently and quickly than getting hints one at a time over many months from an online Q&A site.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune, firstly, sorry for the mistake about rudder and rudder pedal. Second, I have accepted. Third, what I need to study from the link above? It is about **ERCO Ercoupe 415-C**. The cockpit above is Cessna 152's.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune, please tell me how the yoke linked to the rudder pedals so it can be functioned as steering wheel? That will solve the question in this post.

Comment: The Ercoupe link explains why it's unusual, why it had no independent control of rudders, and why nobody copied this design that was intended to make car drivers more comfortable in an airplane.
The Ercoupe's yoke controlled ailerons AND rudder AND nosewheel.
No other airplane's yoke controls the nosewheel.
The C152 is utterly traditional in that the yoke has nothing to do with the rudder or the nosewheel.

Comment: @AirCraftLover The yoke in most aircraft is not at all linked to the rudder pedals. Steering on the ground is done completely with your feet. You push on the left pedal to go left, push on the right pedal to go right. It is linked through a system of pulleys/bungies to the steerable nose wheel.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @RonBeyer, nice info. That help me understand how an airplane controlled when in ground.